# Lifting Heegaard splittings to the universal cover

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

Let $M = H_\alpha \cup H_\beta$ be a closed connected Heegaard split 3-manifold with $\Sigma = H_\alpha \cap H_\beta$.  Let $\tilde{M}$ be the universal cover of $M$ and let $\tilde{\Sigma}$ be the lift of $\Sigma$ to $\tilde{M}$.  Similarly let $\tilde{H_\alpha}$ and $\tilde{H_\beta}$ be the lifts of $H_\alpha$ and $H_\beta$.

What can I say about the topology of $\tilde{\Sigma}$?  Is it necessarily connected?  What is the subgroup of $\pi_1(\Sigma)$ that $\tilde{\Sigma}$ corresponds to?  I imagine that it can be written in terms of the kernels of the inclusions $\pi_1(\Sigma) \to \pi_1(H_\alpha)$ and $\pi_1(\Sigma) \to \pi_1(H_\beta)$?

What about $\tilde{H_\alpha}$ and $\tilde{H_\beta}$?  In the case where the cover is finite-sheeted is $\tilde{M} = \tilde{H_\alpha} \cup \tilde{H_\beta}$ a Heegaard splitting?

I would really love a reference that addresses these sorts of ideas.  I am sorry for such an open ended question - I am not really initiated in the 3-manifold world and I do not know where to look for these things.

Comment: The $3$-torus does not have a genus 1 Heegaard decomposition.

Comment: @NickL yes you are right...my bad.

Comment: I think the lifts should all be connected because you can choose representatives for everything in $\pi_1$ to lie within the surface, so it will lift to a path in the $\tilde \Sigma$